# Is there a way programmatically transform coordinates (and the derivations) from one frame to another?

Tags: frame, transformation

I got a question like this:

assuming there are several cartesian coordinate systems (all are 2D or 3D, also if there is a universal solution can covers 1D or 4D or even higher dimensions will be beautiful though not neccessary).

one frame is refered as world-frame(refered as `W`, which is fixed, ground-truth), motion info of two obejcts (refered as `X`,`Y`) is measured according to this world-frame. we got

```
XW = [
      xw1(0) , xw1(1) , xw1(2), ... xw1(m);
      xw2(0) , xw2(1) , xw2(2), ... xw2(m);
      xw3(0) , xw3(1) , xw3(2), ... xw3(m);
      ...
      xwn(0) , xwn(1) , xwn(2), ... xwn(m);
     ]
```

this matrix `XW` in size of `(n, m)` means the measurements of object `X` w.r.t frame `W`, where `xwn(m)` mean the m-order derivative of the n-th measurement, e.g. in a 2D case,

`xw1(0)` is position in `x` axis in `W`, `xw2(0)` is position in `y` axis, `xw3(0)` is yaw/heading angle in the `W` frame;

then

`xw1(1)` is velocity in `x` axis in `W`, `xw2(1)` is velocity in `y` axis, `xw3(1)` is yaw-rate in the `W` frame;

also

`xw1(2)` is acceleration in `x` axis in `W`, `xw2(2)` is acceleration in `y` axis, `xw3(2)` is angular acceleration in the `W` frame;

if this is a 3D case , xw1(0)~xw6(0) should be x/y/z/pitch/yaw/roll, xw1(1)~xw6(1) should be vx/vy/vz/pitch-rate/yaw-rate/roll-rate, xw1(2) ~ xw6(2) should be correspoding (angular-)acceleration, xw1(3)~xw6(3) shoudl be the corresponding jerk;

besides, not all DOF is neccesary for measure, that is to say, for example in a 3D we only have `xw1~wx4` (maybe `x/y/z/yaw`) for concern and calculation.

similar there is a `YW` measurement;

next, we have a local-frame fixed to object `Y` , my question is whether there is a way that can programmatically transform coordinates `XW` to `XY` according to the info of `XW` and `YW` we got?

where `XY` means measurement of obejct `X` w.r.t the frame fixed to `Y`, i.e.

```
XY = TRANSFORM(XW, YW)
```

what is this `TRANSFORM`? any theoretical support? or formulas that can be programmatically implemented?

this problem in reality could be as follow: i got a global sensor can detect two robots' motion according to ground, and share this information between the two robots, then without other information(or more sensors deployed on robots), one robot could calculate the other one's relative motion w.r.t itself, just by calculating the `TRANSFORM`.

I have investigated something, but looks like not enough, e.g. :

tf2 looks like can only handle the position transform but not velocity/acceleration/rotational motion;

theoretical mechanics and transport motion may involve with this, but looks not a programmatically way and involves a lot of formula-deduce according to specific scenarios.

lie-groups looks like can do this but I only found some formula proof process, didn't find a clearly conclusion of how to use it, if any practical experience would be a great help;

thanks for any advice and discussion.